# Can I use HighCharts Demos without paying

Tags: highcharts

I am going to add Highcharts to my personal website which has google adsense on it ! I cant afford Highcharts But will I be able to use highcharts demos available in jsfiddle for free !

Comment: In [some cases](https://shop.highsoft.com/faq#Non-Commercial-0) you don't need to pay.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Highcharts Twitter handle that if I am using it for commercial purpose in the sense generating revenue by any way from the site I have to get licence ! So I am not going to use it ! I am using google charts for my purpose !